# Разница функций между float, void, int

Tags: c++

За все мое обучение на программиста, так и не затрагивалась тема, причина использования функций `void`, `int` или `float`.

В данный момент, я чаще всего или почти всегда использую в С++ `void foo()`, может кто из гуру объяснить разницу, между использования того или иного типа функций.

Может для кого-то этот вопрос покажется глупым, думаю многим новичкам в программировании, он поможет.

Comment: вопрос в чем разница между `void foo()` и, к примеру, `int foo()`?

Comment: @Chubatiy да, между `void foo()`, `int foo()` или `float foo()`

Comment: В оставшемся от С синтактисе `void foo()` идентификатор перед именем функции это тип возвращаемого значения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле это не функции, а возвращаемый тип функции

```
void foo(){
 return; //ничего не возвращает, обычно return в конце функции не пишут
}

int foo(){
  return 5; //функция возвращает целое число
}

float foo(){
  return 1.1f; //функция возвращает число с плавающей точкой одинарной точности
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`void` - ничего не возвращает

`int` - возвращает целое число размер которого зависит от системы (32 или 64 бита)

`float` - возвращает число с точкой